# H2 Span Background - Width: Auto not working as it should

Tags: css, html

I'm back with more questions!

It's likely something very simple, but it has confused the hell out of me. I have a layout set-up so that the H2 text on pages and posts (Wordpress) has a background image next to it on both sides, accomplished by use of span:before and span:after.

Here is how it is working correctly and what I would like the overall CSS to achieve:

http://www.weburton.co.uk/content/demo/?page_id=121

This is currently achieved by min and max-widths in the CSS. And I've had the width part set to auto, where it is under a parent element with the width of the page. I don't understand how the lines aren't automatically resizing based on the H2's width. See, the problem here:

http://www.weburton.co.uk/content/demo/?p=36

Here is the CSS that is used:

```css
#pagewrapper{ 
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; 
    padding-top: 140px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 span:before{background:url("http://weburton.co.uk/content/demo/wp-content/themes/epic/images/header_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll left center transparent;content:" ";height:1px;margin-right:15px; left: 0%; position:absolute; margin-top: 15px; min-width: 25%; max-width: 50%; width: auto; }
h2 span:after{background:url("http://weburton.co.uk/content/demo/wp-content/themes/epic/images/header_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll right center transparent;content:" ";height:1px; margin-left:15px; right: 0%;  position:absolute; min-width: 25%; max-width: 50%; width: auto;  margin-top: 15px; }
```

Basically, I've exhausted all options that I can think of. Is there something I'm missing here or is there another way to go about achieving this styling using something else but span that is easier?

Oh and I know I have some redundant styling calls, I'm in the process of cleaning it up. :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: In the http://www.weburton.co.uk/content/demo/?page_id=121 it does not work correctly, there is less amount of text simply. Try to add in firebug "Selena Gomez Launches New Album" instead of simple "Selena Gomez" and you'll see that it is the same

Comment: Sorry about the wording. That is how it is supposed to look-the overall goal. I was aware that there was less text and therefore the formatting worked correctly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that is what you want

Remove `min-width` and `max-width` from  `h2 span:before` and `h2 span:after`

```
h2 span {
    position:relative;   
}
h2 span:before {
    left: -25%;
    width: 20%;
}
h2 span:after {
    right: -25%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: It works and I've recently updated the right and left to -100px each, but the main point was for it to wrap to any unique heading; e.g. long or short, the bg image would span accordingly. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: It will wrap. Try to remove some text in firebug

Comment: I've just tested it on Firebug and the BG image is not growing in width or shrinking depending on what is contained in the H2 title. For instance, I removed "New", so the headline read "Selena Gomez Launches Album" - yet the span BG was not dynamic.

Comment: Updated answer. Remove min-width and max-width from h2 span:before and h2 span:after. And set width of the `before` and `after` to 150px

Comment: I'm still getting the same issues, despite removing the min-width and max-width. Its just wrapping about 70px on each end now.

Comment: Just did that. I actually don't think there is a way to accomplish what I'm asking; perhaps I'll just have to edit the styling and spacing of the text so that it doesn't take up too much space and stick within the boundaries, instead.

Comment: what do you actually need? I thought that you want two strips stuck to the both ends of your text.

Comment: But I wanted the "two strips" to be dynamic in width; e.g. if I have a long title like the one we have been working with "Selena Gomez Launches New Album" then there would be short "strips". If I have a short title like "Information", then the "strips" would be larger. The plan was to have them automatically resize based on what was contained in the H2 tag.

Comment: remove `overflow:hidden`, set width and left/right bigger than 25%, may be 35%, so the difference in size of the strips will be more obvious

Comment: I'll just stick with the pre-defined widths for the strips and crunch the text to fit within. Thanks for all your assistance though! :)

Answer (score 0):

without a fiddle it's hard to give you a definite answer, but I think that if you try changing the display property to `display: inline-block` it should do the trick.

This will cause the element to act as a block element while still being displayed inline (thus preserving your current layout - block elements typically take up the full available width and are followed by linebreaks).

Comment: No cigar, sorry. That was one of the display properties that I did not try; I did try inline and block and none of them worked either. This is the first time that I have used the span:before and after formatting-its my belief that the span should be able to wrap around the H2 tag, am I correct? Or do I need to actually set the maximum width of a H2? 

Admittedly, that would leave the span tag serving little purpose... or am I just talking complete nonsense?

Comment: The `<span>` is to `<label>` as `<div>` is to `<p>` - in other words, it is purely unformatted and can be used to wrap anything. If changing to inline-block did not work, try changing the tag to the `<div>` and adjust any height settings as needed.

Comment: the other thing you can try is changing the H2 tag to just a plain span, p, or div tag - using the H2 tag isn't really necessary here - I try never to use H tags, just because I prefer to specify my font size and the amount of white-space between my elements on my own, so changing that may help you as well